# How to keep the result set in SAS

Tags: sas

How can I write the result set from a select statement in a sas table ?

```
execute (
SELECT * 
FROM test
)
...

/* How to write this into SAS table now 
data mytable;
set theAboveResultSet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using some sort of pass-through SQL here.

```
proc sql;
connect to oledb (init_String= ...) ;
select * from connection to oledb (
  select ... from ... 
);
quit;
```

That is for a simple select query.  If you're doing an execute (such as a stored procedure), you need to have that Stored Proc save the data to a temporary table or view and perform a select from that.  As far as I know you can't select from an execute directly.

Comment: Obviously, change `oledb` to your method of connecting to the RDBMS.

Comment: I am using odbc . I tried the above method with odbc it does not recognize it

Comment: As long as you substitute ODBC in both places it should work fine; I've used this with both OLEDB and ODBC numerous times.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add CREATE TABLE xxx AS in your PROC SQL statement:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
  CREATE TABLE mylib.mydataset AS
  SELECT ...
  ;
QUIT;
```